# Cmake can not find -lcudart when compiling

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda

I realize this has been asked a lot, but I've been trying to debug this for a day and I hadn't come accross a solution, which would solve my problem.

So, I have a makefile:

```
if(GPU)
#  set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER /usr/bin/gcc-4.8)
  find_package(CUDA QUIET)

  if(CUDA_FOUND)

    include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    message(STATUS "CUDA detected")
    set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS OFF)
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
    set(CUDA_HOST_COMPILER g++)
    set(CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)

    file(GLOB CUDA_FILES *.cu)
    list( APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;")
    CUDA_COMPILE(CU_O ${CUDA_FILES})

    # SETUP FOR CPP FILES
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
    include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

    # COMPILE AND LINK
    cuda_add_executable(main_test ${CU_O} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})

    message(STATUS "File setup seems ok.")

  else()

    message(STATUS "NO CUDA DETECTED! GPU-based compilation canceled.")

  endif()

endif()
```

I want to separately compile the .cu files and at some point merge them into a simple static library. My problem is, that at this point I can't even compile a single executable. If I try to use only nvcc test.cu -o test, it compiles perfectly, so this appears to be a system-level error.

What I tried:

Linking cudart separately with:

```
ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.a /usr/local/lib/
```

Then I came accross [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/487573/linker-error-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lcudart/) great post, where the proposed solution was to use ${CUDA_LIBRARIES} variable, yet this also returned:

```
Linking CXX executable main_test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcudart
```

I also tried plain simple:

```
alias nvcc="nvcc -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart"
```

But still no success. Am I missing somthing obvious? Thank you.

EDIT: VERBOSE MODE ADDED:

```
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   date_time
--   filesystem
--   system
--   regex
--   iostreams
-- GSL using gsl-config /usr/bin/gsl-config
-- Using GSL from /usr
-- :::OPENMM_INCLUDE_DIR:         
-- CUDA detected -- LiSiCa library
-- CUDA_LIBRARIES = /usr/lib/libcudart.so
-- File setup seems ok.
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   regex
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Comment: Could you provide the command that CMake tries to execute? You can have this detail by running `VERBOSE=1 make`; also, what is the content of `${CUDA_LIBRARIES}` (eg. add `message(STATUS "CUDA_LIBRARIES = ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}"` in your `CMakeLists.txt` and run `cmake`).

Comment: I added the code to makefile, the post is edited with the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you provide the library to link to the `cuda_add_executable()`:

```
cuda_add_executable(main_test ${CU_O} ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

Given the log, it is clear that the content of `CUDA_LIBRARIES` is not used in the compilation line, because the variable does contain the absolute path to the library.

I don't know for CUDA specifically, but usually with CMake you provide only the files to compile/process to the `add_executable()`, and provide the library to link with, with `target_link_libraries()`; which would give:

```
cuda_add_executable(main_test ${CU_O})
target_link_libraries(main_test ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: interesting, when doing this, it throws: nvcc fatal   : nvcc supports '--relocatable-device-code=true (-rdc=true)', '--device-c (-dc)', and '--device-link (-dlink)' only when targeting sm_20 or higher

Comment: @sdgawerzswer When looking into the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindCUDA.html), it says that `cuda_compile()` is to be used with `add_executable()`, while `cuda_add_executable()` seems to do both; maybe that? Or maybe your flags in `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS` are incorrect? Only guess, again I have never used CUDA. HTH anyway!

Comment: Thank you, I guess I need to fiddle with the flags some more.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by disabling CXX flags added upper in the build tree.